# +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks] crash

Tags: ios, webrtc, voip, ios13, callkit

I've integrated VoIP based calling functionality in iOS. For each call, I'm getting VoIP push from server to initiate the call.

```
// AppDelegate.swift

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    guard type == .voIP else {
        completion()
        return
    }

    SBLog("VOIPpayload: \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
    
    if let userInfoDic = payload.dictionaryPayload as? [String:Any] {

        if let isChatNotification = userInfoDic["notificationType"] as? String, isChatNotification == "chat" { // We're not sending VoIP for iOS 13 Chat. So this block won't execute
            
            if let connectionService = AppDelegate.sdkManager?.getConnectionService(), let stream = connectionService.xmppStream, stream.isConnected {

                if !SDKManager.shared.getPresenceService().gotAckForSentAvailableAwayPresence {
                    AppDelegate.sdkManager?.getPresenceService().makeOffline()
                    AppDelegate.sdkManager?.getPresenceService().runForwardMAM()
                }
                SBLog("XMPP is Connected (by VOIP)")
            }
            else{
                // If user logged IN
                if let userDict :NSDictionary = getUsersData() {
                    let isMarker = (userInfoDic["isMarker"] as? Bool) ?? false
                    if isMarker {
                        AppDelegate.sdkManager?.getInbox().getInboxMarkers()
                    }else{
                        let bearerToken = userDict.value(forKey: BearerTokenKey) as! String
                        let myUserID = userDict.value(forKey: UserIdKey) as! String
                        // #72114. Multiple Stream connection. When receiving notification in BG.
                        AppDelegate.connectionService?.connectionType = .fromNotificationService
                        
                        if let connectionService = AppDelegate.sdkManager?.getConnectionService(), let _ = connectionService.xmppStream {
                            AppDelegate.connectionService?.manualConnect()
                        }else{
                            AppDelegate.connectionService?.connect(userId: myUserID, password: "", bearerToken:bearerToken)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion()
            }
        }
        else {
            
            /*
            // Checking if user logged in. 
            guard User.shared.isLogined == true else {
                completion()
                return
            }
            */
            
            self.socketStackFlushingInProgress = false
            self.socketQueue = SBQueue()
            
            callPayloadDict = userInfoDic
            
            if !isSocketConnected() {
                AppDelegate.sharedInstance.connectWithSocket()
            }
            
            let roomId = self.callPayloadDict?["roomId"] as? String ?? ""
            let name = self.callPayloadDict?["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let profilePicture = self.callPayloadDict?["profilePicture"] as? String ?? ""
            let userId = self.callPayloadDict?["userId"] as? String ?? ""
            let callType = self.callPayloadDict?["callType"] as? String ?? ""
                            
            let callObj = CallRecord(name: name, profilePicture: profilePicture, roomId: roomId, userId: userId, callType: callType, callUUID: UUID())
            
            CallKitHandler.sharedInstance.showIncomingCall(callObj: callObj, isFromVOIP: true) { (provider, update, newUUID, call) in
                
                provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: newUUID, update: update) { error in
                    
                    if error == nil {                            
                    CallKitHandler.sharedInstance.reportEventsPostCallReporting(callObj: callObj, completion: {_ in
                            
                            CallKitHandler.sharedInstance.callManager.add(call: call)
                            
                            if !User.shared.isLogined {
                                CallKitHandler.sharedInstance.clearCalls()
                            }
                            else {
                                self.validateCallerDetails(callUUID: newUUID, provider: provider, callObj: callObj)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    
                    completion()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the implementation of **CallKitHandler's showIncomingCall** method as given below,

```
// CallKitHandler.swift

/// Method to process incoming call.
/// - Parameters:
///   - callObj: call obj
///   - isFromVOIP: isCall from VoIP or Socket
///   - completion: completion callback
func showIncomingCall(callObj : CallRecord, isFromVOIP : Bool, completion: ((CXProvider, CXCallUpdate, UUID, Call) -> Void)?) {
    
    self.callObj = callObj
    
    if CallKitHandler.sharedInstance.connectedCallObj == nil {
        AppDelegate.sharedInstance.isCallConnected = false
    }
    
    self.callType = .incoming
    self.ongoingRoomID = callObj.roomId
    
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.supportsHolding = false
    update.supportsGrouping = false
    update.supportsUngrouping = false
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: callObj.name ?? "")
    update.hasVideo = callObj.callType == SBCallType.video.getCallTypeForSocket() ? true : false
    
    let newUUID = callObj.callUUID ?? UUID() // UUID(uuidString: callObj.roomId ?? "") ?? UUID()
    
    callObjUUID = newUUID
            
    let call = Call(uuid: newUUID, handle: callObj.name ?? "", roomID: callObj.roomId ?? "")
    
    completion?(self.provider, update, newUUID, call)
}
```

I've properly initiated **reportNewIncomingCall** method from CallKit for each VoIP push notification. But still, I'm getting below crashes in Firebase.

> +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Killing app because it never posted
> an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push
> callback.

Also, Even a single time, I didn't face this app crash while app using/debugging in my phone. (ie., I didn't see the app crash visually)

Any suggestions for this issue ??

Comment: Can you show the `showIncomingCall` implementation?

Comment: Sure @Marco. Will update the question

Comment: Are the "send...Event" functions async? Maybe you're doing too much stuff before reporting the new incoming call. It could be that in some older devices and in some circumstances the new call is not reported on time.

Comment: @Marco Let me try with moving those operations after reportNewIncomingCall and will update here.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan Did you got a solution on this??

Comment: @Marco I moved the functionalities after reportNewIncomingCall is reported. But still, this crashes occurring in crashlytics logs.

Comment: @RushangPrajapati No fix available for now.

Comment: @Marco Updated latest code to handle didReceiveIncomingPush and showIncomingCall method code.

Answer (score 0):

If the app continues to crash, it means that in some circumstances you don't report a new incoming call. Maybe because of a bug you're sending chat messages through VoIP push to some iOS 13 devices, who knows. You should report a fake call for any branch of your code that doesn't call `reportNewIncomingCall` (as I've already described int [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595538/1082528) answer).

```
func reportFakeCall(completion: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
    let vCallId = UUID()
    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(
        with: vCallId,
        update: callUpdate,
        completion: { error in
            completion()
            self.endCall(with: vCallId) // CXEndCallAction transaction
    })
}
```

The fact that you don't see any crash while using the app it's normal: the app only crashes when it's in background.