# CallKit reportNewIncomingCall completion called but still getting "Killing app because it never posted an incoming call ..." crash

Tags: swift, voip, ios13, callkit, pushkit

This is my first time using `PushKit` and `CallKit` combination to build a VoIP feature. I noticed that starting from iOS 13 it is mandatory to **report** a PushKit VoIP push, otherwise the app will crash.

Due to this regulation I proceeded to implement the `reportNewIncomingCall` method inside `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` and made sure that its completion is successfully called, which it did,  because the breakpoint I placed within the completion block was activated.

However, not long after that, the app crashed and showed "Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP callback", which is weird because previously the completion block was called.

Does anybody know why this happens?

This is the code of `reportNewIncomingCall` I implemented:

```swift
let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
callUpdate.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: session)
callUpdate.localizedCallerName = username
callUpdate.hasVideo = true
callUpdate.supportsDTMF = false
        
let uuid = {{some uuid}}
        
provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: callUpdate, completion: { error in
    if let error = error {
         print("reportNewIncomingCall error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion()
    }
})
```

**EDIT**

This is the `pushRegistry(_, didReceiveIncomingPushWith...)` code:

```swift
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if type == .voIP {
         guard let payloadData = payload.dictionaryPayload as? [String: Any],
            let data = payloadData["data"] as? [String: Any],
            let typeCall = data["type"] as? String else { completion();return }

         if typeCall == "OPEN_ACTIVITY_CALL" {
              guard let userName = data["userName"] as? String else { completion();return }
              self.appleCallKit?.showIncomingCall(username: userName)
         }
         completion()
    }
}
```

`self.appleCallKit?.showIncomingCall(username: userName)` method executes `reportNewIncomingCall` in the previous code block

Comment: Can you provide the entirety of your code, starting from `func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType)` until when `provider.reportNewIncomingCall(...` is called?

Comment: Edited, showing `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` code @pepsy

Comment: You have some `guard`s and `if`s in your code, that might prevent CallKit from being called. For this rule of using VoIP pushes, it doesn't matter if the push is well formatted or not, it doesn't care if you received a call or not. Every single time you receive a VoIP push, you MUST report a new incoming call to CallKit. If you see that something is wrong and you don't want to do so, your only option is to report a new incoming call and asynchronously tell it the call ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem could be the `DispatchQueue.main.async`. This will cause your `completion` handler to be executed later in a future run loop and probably for the system is too late.

Just try to remove it:

```
provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: callUpdate, completion: { error in
    if let error = error {
        print("reportNewIncomingCall error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    completion()
})
```

**EDIT**

In the new code you've provided, I can see at least three errors that can lead to the crash.

1. If one of the `guard` statements fails, you will not report a new incoming call, hence the app crashes. You should do something like this:

```
guard let payloadData = payload.dictionaryPayload as? [String: Any],
    let data = payloadData["data"] as? [String: Any],
    let typeCall = data["type"] as? String else { 
        reportFakeCall(completion) // <---
        return 
    }
```

Report a fake call and immediately terminate it.

2. Given that the `reportNewIncomingCall` is an asynchronous method, you are not guaranteed that the `completion()` of the `pushRegistry(didReceiveIncomingPushWith...)` will be called after the completion of the `reportNewIncomingCall`. So, in some cases, the app will crash because you havn't reported a new incoming call before the completion. You should do something like this:

```
if typeCall == "OPEN_ACTIVITY_CALL" {
    guard let userName = data["userName"] as? String else { 
       reportFakeCall(completion) // <-- As in point 1
       return
    }
    self.appleCallKit?.showIncomingCall(username: userName, completion) // <---
}
```

Pass the completion handler to the `showIncomingCall` and call it inside the completion of the `reportNewIncomingCall`.

3. If `typeCall` is not equal to `OPEN_ACTIVITY_CALL` you don't report a new incoming call and the app crashes.

```
if typeCall == "OPEN_ACTIVITY_CALL" {
    ...
} else {
    reportFakeCall(completion)
}
```

You can implement the `reportFakeCall` method as follows:

```
func reportFakeCall(completion: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
    let vCallId = UUID()
    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(
        with: vCallId,
        update: callUpdate,
        completion: { error in
            completion()
            self.endCall(with: vCallId) // CXEndCallAction transaction
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.. I still get crashes

Comment: I've just seen you're updated question and updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I see, there might be cases where the payload isn't complete so guard statement fails.. a question though, inside `reportFakeCall(_:)`, how do I report incoming call and immediately terminate it? @Marco

Comment: I've added an implementation of `reportFakeCall` to the answer

Comment: Implemented your solution and especially the `reportFakeCall`, it actually doesn't crash anymore.. I guess there was a problem with my guard statements. Thanks @Marco!